# Which external sites are required for Stack Overflow to work properly?

Tags: discussion, support

At my workplace almost every site is blocked. At first they have blocked Google, but after I made a request they gave me access to use Google. Then I found that Stack Overflow is blocked, but after I made a second request, they gave me access to Stack Overflow, but now unfortunately Stack Overflow is not working properly and I am not able to login.

After carefully observing (browser console and browser network), I came to know that they have blocked jQuery Google CDN.

I made a request again and got access to all jQuery CDN and now I can login, but unfortunately Stack Overflow chat is not working properly. I found the following problems:

1. I am not able to filter or search. When I type a user name or chat room name, then the rooms or users are not filtered.
2. When I click on join room then it only shows loading... please wait for second.

I am not able to find out which other external sites are blocked. Which external sites are necessary for Stack Overflow to work properly?

Comment: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)

Comment: In particular the "What else do I need" section of the above linked post.

Comment: Please let me know where you work so I never consider working there

Comment: Seriously, does your job just block the entire Internet by default? Do you have to ask permission to get to anything other than the company Intranet (assuming you have one)?

Comment: Why would anyone ever block *Google*?

Comment: interesting case. you never know.

Comment: @johnnyRose: Because Google lets you view cached versions of other sites? So Google = Internet in a way.

Comment: Never knew SO or Google were NSFW :). Things are changing!

Comment: my *previous* company had jQuery Google CDN blocked too, leaving SO as a read only websiite...

Comment: Lots of the same issues in China.

Comment: In *alot* of companies being able to access online chat rooms is banned. I can understand having access to SO & Google etc but you might find it harder to justify getting the chat to work.

Comment: Leave your job. If they don't trust you, they're not worthy of you.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter: The question indicates that they've opened up every single site he's asked for.  They distrust *someone* on the local network, but it doesn't seem to be OP.

Comment: Of course it's all about trust, @BenVoigt. What do you think they would do when OP requests unlimited access? Permission to go to the bathroom, Sir?

Comment: @Stephan It might just be a security precaution, which in some industries is pretty standard. Honestly, he has internet and can request access to all the sites he needs for work - that's great. There are people working in completely sealed off networks, what do you think those would give for simple SO access?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Google can be _very_ NSFW if you use it right.

Comment: At my workplace I can access all SE sites except Gaming.

Comment: @Zenadix Same here, but I think that's because they got tired of me getting on Gaming on my lunch break. :)

Comment: In addition to the standard Joel Test questions, "do employees have unrestricted access to the Internet" is a question you should ask during an interview.

Comment: @Kendra - But it's your damn lunch break...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to open the network tab in dev tools and find what all is blocked. Just FYI that can save you time next time you want some other website to be fully unblocked.

Answer (score 29):

As far as I know...

- `*://i.stack.imgur.com` - Imgur is the hosting platform for user-contributed images
- `*://*.sstatic.net` - The Stack Exchange CDN - hosts images, stylesheets and the like
- `*://*.stackexchange.com` and `*://*.stackoverflow.com` - Who wouldn't want to visit other SE sites?
- `*://ajax.googleapis.com` - Common JavaScript libraries (like jQuery) hosted by Google CDN
- `*://cdn.mathjax.org` for certain SE sites

<sup>The `*` denotes a wildcard.</sup>

Note that...

- User contributed *links* aren't listed, mostly because there's a million and one of 'em.

Comment: I believe you can link to images anywhere, not just on imgur, no?

Comment: There's also Stack Snippet.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's not true I don't think. I believe I"ve used the `<img>` tags before to embed a non-imgur link and have the image display in-line in the question/answer.

Comment: Yeah there was even an issue with ImageShack hosted images that had died out appearing as ads. There are definitely images that are displayed despite not being stack hosted. The difference is whether they're uploaded to SO.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Probably a special case, but the standard image uploader (which uploads images by link and from a filesystem) puts it through `i.stack.imgur.com`

Comment: @Zizouz212 that makes sense. I've never used the image uploader, just always embedded images directly.

Comment: @psubsee2003: _"Visible images in posts are always from stack.imgur.com. No exceptions."_ False.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: You _should_ use the uploader because then `i.stack.imgur.com` is used. Apparently you're making your posts rely on a lot of off-site content. :( (Yes, imgur is "off-site", but for the purposes of this conversation the `stack.imgur.com` domain is as "on-site" as it gets.)

Comment: @Zizouz212: to be more strict, it's just `ajax.googleapis.com` not the whole domain `*.googleapis.com`. The difference is important for those who run NoScript/Firefox because you can have untrusted user-uploaded scripts under `storage.googleapis.com` (Google Cloud Storage).

Comment: It's community wiki, so feel free to edit it yourself @Amro. Just a little fact, I didn't edit that in :)

Answer (score 20):

To address a particular comment (emphasis mine):

> @JörgWMittag Yes and no. **Visible images in posts are always from stack.imgur.com. No exceptions.** But anyone can provide a link to an image, it just will be a link - [psubsee2003](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315207/which-external-sites-are-required-for-stack-overflow-to-work-properly?cb=1#comment297416_315221)

That's not true. Here's a non-imgur image:

[image: I'm pretty exceptional; wouldn't you agree?]

Achieved via markdown as:

```
![](someurl)
```

or through HTML as:

```
<img src="someurl">
```

Comment: Can't see that image from China.